# При наведении показываются точки в последнем пункте меню

Tags: вёрстка, css3

Всем привет! Возникла такая проблема: сделал вертикальное меню, при наведении градиент зеленого цвета. Само меню закруглено снизу (сверху нет), при наведении на последний пункт выскакивают какие-то еще зеленые точки см. рисунок

[image: точки в пункте меню]

HTML:

```
<div class="block menu">
                <div class="content">
                    <ul class="m">
                        <li><b><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></b></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Пункт 4</a>
        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт 5</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Пункт 6</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS

```
.block.menu li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
.block.menu li a {
  line-height: 200%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.block.menu li a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to bottom, #a8dca8 0%, #84cd84 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #000;
}
.block.menu .m {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(to right, #222222 0%, #555555 100%) repeat-x scroll 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
   padding: 0;
}
.block.menu .m li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
  border-top: 1px solid #6f6f6f;
}
.block.menu .m li a:hover {
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a8dca8 0%, #84cd84 100%);
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
.block.menu .m li:last-child {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
.block.menu .m li:last-child a {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  padding: 6px 10px 5px;
}
.block.menu .m li:last-child a:hover {
  padding: 6px 10px 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}
.block.menu .head {
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
```

вот код выложил http://jsfiddle.net/ybae4n9b/1/ что только не делал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема вот в этом:

```
.block.menu .m li a:hover {
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a8dca8 0%, #84cd84 100%);
}
```

`border-image` не корректно работает при закругленных углах.

Поменяйте вот на это:

```
.block.menu .m li a:hover {
  border-color: #84cd84;
}
```

Визуально разница не видна, а цель достигнута :)